# "self" is lost when using a decorator

Tags: python-3.x, decorator

I am trying to implement a decorator for my plugin based IRC bot.

Adding a command ("!command arg1 arg2") based on the function name should look like this:

```
class CorePlugin:
    @BotCommand
    def mycommand(self, arguments):
        self.bot.privmsg("#mychannel", "invoked !mycommand %s" % " ".join(arguments))
```

The decorator looks like this:

```
class BotCommand:
    def __init__(self, func):
        events.add(func.__name__, func)
```

Adding the command works fine.
This is my `Events` class:

```
class Events:
    def __init__(self):
        self.events = {}

    def add(self, cmd, func):
        self.events[cmd] = func

    def call(self, cmd, args):
        for c, f in self.events.items():
            if c == cmd:
                f(None, args)
```

`Events.call` is being called successfully within my `Bot` class after a PRIVMSG came in, but I need to pass the actual object (of `CorePlugin`) to my decorated function by hand. Currently it's just `None`. `func.__self__` is somehow lost within the process.

Do you have an idea on how to approach that?

Comment: `Events.call` is called upon message arriving somewhere? What exactly invokes it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

forget the decorator
here it is more nuisance than a help

in `__init__` method of `CorePlugin` put
`BotCommand(self.mycommand)`

problem with 1st solution is that `BotCommand` is initialized before `CorePlugin`,
so `self` does not exist.

This way function `mycommand` "remembers" it should be called with `CorePlugin` object as 1st argument

*note*
I had to erase my other solution because it doesn't work
making **__call__** method in **BotCommand** class **DOESN'T work**
even though it is callable, it doesn't automatically get `CorePlugin` object as an argument
that happens with functions exclusively (which cannot be inherited)